# How to insert elements in an array at a particular index in case the elements are themselves in another array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose, I have two arrays :

A = [1, 2, 3, 4]

B = [10, 20, 30].

and I want to insert B's elements in array A starting from index 1. So, my final array would look like

[1, 10, 20, 30, 2, 3, 4]

I tried to do it with `splice`. But the splice function requires you to provide list of elements, not an array.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just *spread* `B` into the argument list of `splice`:

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const B = [10, 20, 30]
A.splice(1, 0, ...B); // equivalent to `.splice(1, 0, 10, 20 30)`
console.log(A);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Note that [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the array:

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

But, if you are looking to change array `A` then `splice()` is fine as shown on the other answers.

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const B = [10, 20, 30];
const C = [...A.slice(0,1), ...B, ...A.slice(1)];
console.log(C);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice with [Function#apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method or ES6 spread syntax.

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4],

B = [10, 20, 30];

[].splice.apply(A,[1,0].concat(B));

console.log(A)
```

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4],

  B = [10, 20, 30];

A.splice(1, 0, ...B)

console.log(A)
```